# how to make a nested loop break if string.contains() is correct

Tags: java, while-loop, nested

I'm having issues understanding nested loops and their behavior. On the first loop the script asks for 10 digit number otherwise it will keep looping, this works fine. on the second loop, i'm trying to get the program to keep running until users enters "999" anywhere in the phone number. I have some idea but i'm not able to put it together. so if the user enters a 10 digit number but it doesnt contain 999, then it will keep asking to reenter phone number.

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.lang.*;


      public class FormatPhoneNumber {


      public static void main(String[] args) {
      final int numLength=10;
      String phoneNum = null;
      String nineS="999";



        phoneNum=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your telephone number");

            while (phoneNum.length()!=numLength)

        {phoneNum=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "You must re-enter 10 digits as your telephone number.");
        }


        StringBuffer str1 = new StringBuffer (phoneNum);
        str1.insert(0, '(');
        str1.insert(4, ')');
        str1.insert(8, '-');

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your telephone number is " +str1.toString());

              while (phoneNum.contains(nineS))// THIS IS THE ISSUE
              {

        }
      }
 }
```

Comment: You should reduce the example code to relevant lines. I don't think that a JOptionPane is importing for your loop. Where is your loop nested?

Comment: There appears to be no nested loop here. Did you post it wrong?.

Comment: im trying to nest it, but im not sure if im doing it correctly. the two while statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting is when one loop is inside another loop. The code you have provided does not have one.

Typical example of nesting:

```
while( some_condition )
{ 
    do_something..
    while( more_condition )
    {
        do_something_more..
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly, you want to keep on entering numbers and do something with them. But once the user enters a number which has '999' in it, the control has to come out of the loops.

As someone already pointed out, you do not need nested loop to achieve this at all.

```
while( phoneNumber has 10 digits )
{
     do_something..
     if( phoneNumber has '999' anywhere )
     {
         break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if (phoneNum.contains(nineS))
 {}
```

don't use

```
while (phoneNum.contains(nineS))
```

or U can do it this way

```
if (!(phoneNum.contains(nineS)))
          {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Input");
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (phoneNum.length()!=numLength)
    {
        phoneNum=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "You must re-enter 10 digits as your telephone number.");

        StringBuffer str1 = new StringBuffer (phoneNum);
        str1.insert(0, '(');
        str1.insert(4, ')');
        str1.insert(8, '-');

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your telephone number is " +str1.toString());

          if(phoneNum.contains(nineS))// THIS IS THE ISSUE
            break;
    }
```

hope this helps.